# Cummulative to individual using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have following datafile where the values are in cumulative to some point (until row1 > row2):

```
ifile.txt
6
7
10
34
-999
-999
0
2
4
8
12
12
-999
-999
-999
-999
12
13
15
```

I would like to print all individual values without considering the undefined values (i.e. -999).

My desire output is:

```
ofile.txt
6
1
3
24
-999
-999
0
2
2
4
4
0
-999
-999
-999
-999
12
1
2
```

I am trying with `awk'{(if $1 != -999 && [$1] >= [$2]),printf "%s\n",$1-$2}' ifile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another awk idea:

```
$ awk '($1==-999){p=0; print; next}{print $1-p;p=$1}' file
```

The idea is to keep track of the cumulative value of the previous line with the variable `p`. Everytime we hit the value `-999`, we reset `p` to zero. The value of `p` does not need to be initialized as awk assumes that all un-initialized variables are by default an empty string *and* the value 0.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this much simpler awk:

```
awk '{print ($1>=p ? $1-p : $1)} {p = ($1==-999 ? 0 : $1)}' file
```

```
6
1
3
24
-999
-999
0
2
2
4
4
0
-999
-999
-999
-999
12
1
2
```

Comment: This script does not check row1>= row2. As a result it is showing negative values at some point.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the sample data you provided. Anyway this check has been added and script is ever more simplified now. Please check.

Comment: Also I think accepted answer needs further fixes to match your expected output. It prints `12` after 2 `4`s instead of `0`.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for highlighting the problem. Code was modified to handle repeated values (like 12, 12)

Answer (score 1):

In `awk` $1, $2, ... represent different columns, not different rows.

Consider using extra variable `p` to track previous value for the purpose of reversing the cumulative values

```
awk '
    # Save Original Values
{ pp=$1 }
    # Reverse cumulative values
$1 != -999 && p != "" && p != -999 && $1 >= p { $1 = $1 - p }
    # Print value, save for next line
{ print $1 ; p=pp}
' ifile.txt  > ofile.txt
```

Single Line:

```
awk '{ pp=$1 } $1 != -999 && p != "" && p != -999 && $1 >= p { $1 = $1 - p } {  print $1 ; p=pp}' ifile.txt  > ofile.txt
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than it has to be and doesn't work (it won't produce the expected output from the question given the input from the question).

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for highlighting the mismatch with expected values. Condition was modified to cover the case of duplicate values (12, 12 in the sample input).

Comment: good, now it's just much more complicated than it has to be :-). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59609741/1745001 for all you need.